# ContentDialog.ShowAsync() result is always None

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a simple ContentDialog with ContentDialog.XAML:

```
<ContentDialog x:Class="SampleApp.Dialogs"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
           xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
           xmlns:local="using:SampleApp.Dialog"
           xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
           PrimaryButtonClick="OkClick"
           PrimaryButtonText="OK"
           SecondaryButtonText="Cancel"
           SecondaryButtonClick="CancelClick"

           mc:Ignorable="d">
<StackPanel>

    <TextBox 

             Text="{x:Bind NameOne, Mode=TwoWay}" />

    <TextBox  Text="{x:Bind NameTwo, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</StackPanel>
```

In the code-behind:

```
     private void OkClick(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs args)
    {
       this.Hide();
    }
```

When I want to initalize this Dialog by:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
var result = await dialog.ShowAsync();
```

The `result`is always of type `ContentDialogResult.None`. Even if I click "Ok" or "Cancel", but it should be at least `ContentDialogResult.Primary` when I click "Ok". It this an expected behavior?

Comment: Can you try to remove your OkClick handler? I think dialog will close anyway. It seems you overriding default button behavior. So you need to take care of return value by yourself in such case.

Comment: @YuriS: This actually solved the problem. I somehow override the default action with this.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void OkClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Result = MyResult.Yes;
    // Close the dialog
    dialog.Hide();
}
```

Comment: This won't work, as you _have_ to create a custom enum to set the result to the result. I want the _default_ enum.

Comment: if it is good enough for you to remove handler please mark it as answered or you still need help with returning default enum if possible?

Comment: Nobody prevents you to define your result variable as default enum type

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the  `PrimaryButtonClick="OkClick"` , OkClick overriding the default action (which is hide) and therefore the result is always `None`. 
Removing this solved the problem.